# Why does the state update but I can't access it via hooks in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, global-state

I'm having trouble accessing my updated global state in react via hooks. I created custom hooks to get away from reducers and anything redux because I'm not a fan of it. Everything is working well but i cannot access my state.

Here is how the global state is set up

```
import React, {useState, useMemo, useContext} from 'react'

function makeStore() {
  // Make a context for the store
  const Context = React.createContext();

  // Make a provider that takes an initialValue
  const Provider = ({ initialValue, children }) => {
    // Make a new state instance (could even use immer here!)
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue);
    // Memoize the context value to update when the state does
    const contextValue = useMemo(() => [state, setState], [state]);

    // Provide the store to children
    return <Context.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
  };

  // A hook to help consume the store
  const useStore = () => useContext(Context);

  return { Provider, useStore };
}

const {Provider, useStore} = makeStore();

export {
  Provider,
  useStore
}
```

I make sure to wrap the store provider around the App component

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router basename="">
    <Provider initialValue={initialState} >
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The App component is clean and mainly used for routes

```
const App = () => 
    <div className="App">
      <Route exact path="/" component={props => <Landing {...props} />} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={props => <Login {...props} />} />
      <Route exact path="/register/:id" component={props => <Register {...props} />}/>
      <PrivateRoute path='/:id' Component={<Content />} />
    </div>



export default App
```

When I hit the login page, enter login info, and click submit, the state updates. The only thing is I can't access the updated state inside my component.

Heres the login component

```
const Login = ({...props}) => {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
    const {auth, setAuth} = useAuth()
    const {loginUser} = AuthApi()
    const onSubmit = data => (async () => {
        const response = await loginUser(data)
        setAuth(response, true)
    })()
    useEffect(() => {
        if(auth.isAuthenticated === true)
            props.history.push('/dashboard')
    }, [])
    return(
        <div className="Auth" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + background + ')'}}>
            <div className="Login">
                <div className="Auth-Form Login-Form">
                    <div className="Form-Header">
                        <h4>
                            <b>Login</b>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="Form">
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="Email"
                                name="email"
                                ref={register({
                                    required: "email required"
                                })}
                            />
                            <br/>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="Password"
                                name="password"
                                ref={
                                    register({
                                        required: "password required"
                                    })
                                }
                            />
                            <br />
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" placeholder="Create Profile"/>
                        </form>
                        <p className="">
                            Don't have an account? <Link to="/register/user">Register</Link>
                        </p>
                        <Link to="/" className="">Back to home</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

and here's the useAuth hook code

```
const useAuth = () => {
    const [{...auth}, setState] = useStore()

    const setAuth = (data, authenticationStatus) => {
        setState(state => {
            state.auth.token = data.token
            state.auth.user = data.user
            state.auth.loading = true
            state.auth.isAuthenticated = authenticationStatus
        })
    }

    return {auth, setAuth}
}
```

when the value of auth.isAutheticated coverts to true in the login component, nothing happens. In the provider the state is updated and even in the useAuth hook I console log the current state and its updated. Yet I can't access it in the login component despite using useEffects? is there something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code only happens like componentdidmount - once:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(auth.isAuthenticated === true)
            props.history.push('/dashboard')
    }, [])
```

change to

```
 useEffect(() => {
            if(auth.isAuthenticated === true)
                props.history.push('/dashboard')
        })
```

Comment: Wow, that actually did something! I ran into another problem tho, when the state is updated and rerenders its an empty object.

Comment: can put the logs or may be live example in codesandbox

Comment: try  useEffect(() => {
            if(auth.isAuthenticated === true)
                props.history.push('/dashboard')
        },[auth.isAuthenticated])